How can I make Spring's @ExceptionHandler work with other exception handling techniques
Assume the following REST endpoints and @ExceptionHandler
@GetMapping("/whatever/{userId}")
MyResponse fetchStuff(@PathVariable("userId") long userId) {
    return new MyResponse();
}

@GetMapping("/list")
List<String> fetchList() {
     throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT, "No data found");
}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class )
ResponseEntity<String> handleException(Exception e) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE).body(e.getMessage());
}

These tests will fail if using the @ExceptionHandler above. Spring automatically throws a MethodArgumentNotValidException when the first test is run. I manually throw a ResponseStatusException when the second test is run. Both are caught by the global exception handler, which is not what I wanted to happen at all.
@Test
void should_return_400_if_userId_is_alphanumeric() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/whatever/{userId}", "ABC")
        .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}

@Test
void should_return_204() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/list")
        .andExpect(status().isNoContent());
    }
}


Adding a global exception handler for Exception.class seems to cause more problems than it solves.
I could add an @ExceptionHandler like this, but that sort of defeats the purpose of using ResponseStatusException.
@ExceptionHandler(ResponseStatusException.class )
ResponseEntity<String> handleResponseStatusException (ResponseStatusException rse) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(rse.getReason(), rse.getStatus());
}

It feels like I want the MethodArgumentNotValidException and the ResponseStatusException to take priority over Exception, but I know that's not how it works.
What's the point of having a global exception handler here? Is there another way to handle this without having to write an @ExceptionHandler for a bunch of exceptions?

Have you tried handling the child using @RestControllerAdvice?

If I am not mistaken, putting the @ExceptionHandler there just makes it apply to all controllers. I think the result would be the same, correct?

Your mistake is writing advice for Exception.class.  Consider a more targeted approach, creating advice for each type of exception you want to handle.  For instance, I always write exception handlers for EntityNotFoundException.class that will return a 404.  Also, note that you never want your exception advice to return a 500 error.  As you define how you will handle exceptions, this will become second nature, but generally, you want to provide back a status code that gives some direction the caller can take.
